# How does a Falcon 9 booster know how far away the ground is?

Tags: spacex, rockets, falcon-9, landing, reentry

In the [latest landing video](https://twitter.com/elonmusk/status/743602894226653184), it seems the Falcon 9 just hovered for a moment above the ship. That being said, it begs the question, how does the booster know where the ground is? Does it purely work off of GPS, a 1 way radar/beacon type system from the landing zone, radar from the rocket, or some means that I'm not aware of?

Comment: [Curb feelers?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curb_feeler) :-)

Comment: A laser based system is probably out, it wouldn't work through the rocket's exhaust

Comment: @DanPichelman Something like that might work for the final touchdown, but not likely to work, say, 10m high.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto That's why I added the smiley.  I suspect the actual solution probably works from even higher than 10m.  A [radar altimeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_altimeter) might be a possibility, but that's just an uninformed guess.

Comment: I think it knows it generally from the system of locating the barge in 3D, same as horizontal offsets. Now how does it know these...

Comment: If it's GPS, even the best GPS systems are off by a few meters sometimes, and a drop from 2m leads to a huge impact... I'd hope there was something better than that.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: Differential GPS is pretty solid. You'd need a GPS reference on the barge for that, but you probably wanted that anyway ;)

Comment: Less so in height..

Comment: "That’s it! That’s a good name – ground!

I wonder if it will be friends with me?"

Comment: 2m drop is much, but if you reduce your descent speed to what your landing gear is designed to withstand, you can just keep descending at constant rate until you find the ground.

Comment: The booster can't hover, or so we've been told. So you can't have a constant rate of decent...

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: And yet... how would you describe what happens here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYRZTERK5-g ? Or here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QyaUjOCxOX0 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Falcon 9 know where the landing barge/pad is?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/8779/how-does-the-falcon-9-know-where-the-landing-barge-pad-is)

Comment: @Christoph okay :-) comments deleted...

Answer (score 7):

When commenting on one of the early water landings, Elon Musk mentioned there's a radar altimeter (which was calibrated for flat, hard surfaces and might have trouble detecting the water surface as a result).
Can't find a primary source for this, though.

Comment: As of [your own answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/22289) on basically the same question the source is the [post launch interview of Elon Musk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SKXSHZUIFBo) from the Falcon Heavy launch.